# Export list of words containing search term, found through either Browser Search (Ctrl+F) or directly using javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, dom, full-text-search, html-parsing

What is the way to get list of words containing the search term?

For e.g on **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API**, I want to get list of words containing **"Audio"** substring. How to export the list in txt form or console.log() it?

`(Ctrl + F)` shows there are 31 words containing "Audio", How to get list of these words?

Comment: Create a script, then run it in the console. Give it a try

Comment: `document.body.textContent.match(/\b(.*audio.*)\b/gim).slice(1)` might be a good starting point.